# Code first, working with relationships, seeding

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, reference, code-first

I would like to simply create a relationship between two entities that already exists..

In my case I have an Album entity which might have multiple Genres(which also is a bunch of entities)

My Album model looks like this:

```
public class AlbumModel : IModel
{
    public List<GenreModel> Genres { get; set; }
    public ArtistModel Artist { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string ArtUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I then want to create a relation ship between a Album model-object and a bunch of GenreModel-objects/entities..

In the "normal" entity framework I would just assign a new EntityKey.. but Im not quite sure of how to do this using code first..
I also noticed that some people has an extra property called xxxxId for the entity they want to create a reference between.. and then simply assign a value to the xxxxId property which some how magically creates the reference between the entities.. and I guess this works fine for a one to one or a one to many relationship.. but I guess that doesnt work for a many to many relationship..or?

Anyway.. this is my GenresModel:

```
public class GenreModel : IModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<AlbumModel> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what I tried before.. but this wont create the relationship..it will only simply create an additional entity/row in my database..

```
var artistRepository = new ArtistRepository();
        var genresRepository = new GenreRepository();

        #region Lordi
        context.Albums.Add
            (
                new AlbumModel
                {
                    Artist = artistRepository.GetByName("Lordi"),
                    ArtUrl = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8f/The_Monster_Show.jpg",
                    Genres = new List<GenreModel> { genresRepository.GetByName("Rock"), genresRepository.GetByName("Hard rock") },
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Price = 3,
                    Title = "The Monster Show",
                }
            );
        context.Albums.Add
            (
                new AlbumModel
                {
                    Artist = artistRepository.GetByName("Lordi"),
                    ArtUrl = "http://www.nuclearblast.de/static/articles/157/157892.jpg/1000x1000.jpg",
                    Genres = new List<GenreModel> { genresRepository.GetByName("Rock"), genresRepository.GetByName("Hard rock") },
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Price = 10,
                    Title = "Zombilation - The Greatest Cuts",
                }
            );
        #endregion
```

...and for the record... no I dont listen to Lordi :).. just dummy data.. and for some wierd spooky reason Lordi was the first band that came in mind..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying those collection properties as you have done will automatically create a many-to-many linking table called `GenreModelAlbumModels`.

However, I suspect that your repository is preventing EF from knowing that there is a relationship. If you're not loading the GenreModel entities in the same data context, it may not know that there is a link between them. As an example, this code works:

```
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        #region Lordi

        context.Albums.Add
            (
                new AlbumModel
                {
                    ArtUrl = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8f/The_Monster_Show.jpg",
                    Genres = new List<GenreModel> { context.Genres.First(i => i.Name == "Rock"), context.Genres.First(i => i.Name == "Hard Rock") },
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Price = 3,
                    Title = "The Monster Show",
                }
            );

        context.SaveChanges();

        #endregion
    }
```

The GenreModels are connected to the same context that we're adding the AlbumModels to, so EF knows that there is a relationship between the entities.

To make sure it's working properly, look for that linking table in your DB. It will be hidden from you in the code.

Comment: Ok.. well I might be misstaken here.. but what if this application is an API where clients are allowed to post in an album for a specific artist that already exists in the database.. I then need to be able to set reference between the new album and the artist.. By simply doing:
newAlbum.Artist = artistRepository.GetByName("Lordi") I would guess that EF would create an additional Lordi artist.. which isnt what I want..

Comment: I also guess that in the example above.. I would also have to do the same thing with the Artist for the album..am I right?

Comment: Well turns out its was me beeing a moron.. :).. my repo created a new context.. instead of reusing/passing the former context down to the repo.. thanks alot for the help :)!

Answer (score 2):

So basically you're trying to set up a many-to-many relationship in EF. I assume there's a table to link Albums and Genres in the database? If so you need to let EF know about the relationship and the table it's stored as I've explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352063/how-can-i-use-sql-many-to-many-table-from-entity-framework/15353298#15353298). You can find a lot of extra information by googling something like "set up many-to-many in Entity Framework".

On a side note you might also want to change your collection properties to virtual so instead of

```
public List<GenreModel> Genres { get; set; }
```

you would have

```
public virtual ICollection<GenreModel> Genres { get; set; }
```

This makes it faster by allowing EF to perform lazy loading on those properties.

Comment: Yes.. If I have understod this right.. the code-first creates this many to many table for me (in my case a table called GenreModelAlbumModel).. 
Thanks alot for the input regarding the virtual and the ICollection :)