# How to Seed all my data properly Code First configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I read this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373592/code-first-working-with-relationships-seeding) and it's a bit similar to mine however I couldn't seem to be getting it to work for me.

I'm trying to seed some test data and in this case it's a few Users. However I'd like to seed their addresses also but I can't.

Here is a snippet of my POCOs

```
 public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phonenumber> Phonenumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Position> Positions { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int Cycle { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

In the configuration file it's as follows:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CWS.Models.ConnectoDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(CWS.Models.ConnectoDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.

        context.Users.AddOrUpdate(u => u.UserId,
                new User
                {
                    Username = "Blackstallion",
                    FirstName = "Gilbert",
                    LastName = "Johnson",
                    Password = "3fZ45SDF",
                    Headline = "Novice",
                    Addresses = new List<Address> { context.Addresses.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Id,
                        new Address
                            {
                                StreetName = "asd",
                                ZipCode = "123",
                                Country = "abc",
                                Cycle = 2
                            });

                }},
                new User
                {
                    Username = "Qaus",
                    FirstName = "Jon",
                    LastName = "Orton",
                    Password = "1564as5F",
                    Headline = "Novice"
                }
                );
    }
}
```

}

I've tried a few different ways but after reading that post it made sense to do it like so, however I can't seem to work it.

**UPDATE**:

As user [Igarioshka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105615/igarioshka) pointed out the AddOrUpdate method is void and thereby I couldn't return any addresses as my example above.

This is my solution:

```
            context.Users.AddOrUpdate(u => u.UserId,
                new User
                    {
                        Username = "Bob",
                        FirstName = "John",
                        LastName = "Doe",
                        Password = "123",
                        Headline = "Elite",
                        Addresses = new List<Address>{
                        new Address
                            {
                                Id = "1",
                                StreetName = "John's Street",
                                ZipCode = "1234",
                                Country = "AB",
                                Cycle = 2
                            },
                        new Address
                            {
                                Id = "2",
                                StreetName = "John's Work",
                                ZipCode = "1234",
                                Country = "AB",
                                Cycle = 3
                            },
                        new Address
                            {
                                Id = "3",
                                StreetName = "John's Super Secret Street",
                                ZipCode = "0000",
                                Country = "AB",
                                Cycle = 44
                            }}

                    }
                    );
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `context.SaveChanges()`...

Comment: @anaximander Is that necessary and could you further explain what that does? :)

Comment: @twice saveChanges() actually saves the changes... without it the data won't be saved to the DB

Comment: @Thewads I can't make sense of it since I can seed an User without any problems when I remove the Address part from the code and for that part I haven't used the `context.SaveChanges()` :/

Comment: @anaximander you don't need to call savechanges, when seeding data like that.

Comment: @Igarioshka I always forget that `Seed` can take care of it for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AddOrUpdate method is void, thus it does not return any addresses.

i would suggest adding the addresses without the context.AddOrUpdate like so:

```
...
Addresses = new List<Address> { 
                    new Address
                        {
                            Id = 1, //depends on if you have an address defined and how your schema is created
                            StreetName = "asd",
                            ZipCode = "123",
                            Country = "abc",
                            Cycle = 2
                        }},
...
```

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550756/how-to-seed-data-with-many-to-may-relations-in-entity-framework-migrations) question, it may help

Comment: Works like a charm, too bad I didn't realize myself that the method is void :D Cheers!